# How to test rest endpoint in Scala using jUnit

Tags: scala, rest, junit

I have rest post endpoint in my Scala service. I would like test them using integration testing jUnit. I looking for some tutorials but I find only examples which using play or other frameworks... I would like use only jUnit. Do you reccomend some examples?

```
class ExampleIntegrationJUnitStyleSpec extends JUnitSuite with Matchers {

  @Test def shouldRespondWithPublicResource(): Unit = {


    //test post endpoint

  }
}

object ExampleIntegrationJUnitStyleSpec {

  private lazy val _myAppRule = new JUnitMyAppRule("integration", 8811)

  @ClassRule
  def myAppRule: JUnitMyAppRule = _myAppRule
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test REST APIs using Specs2 and the Dispatch library (http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html).

Comment: Ok, but I would like use only jUnit and ScalaTest. It's possible?

Comment: I think it should be possible as anyways Web Services consumers need not to be of the same language as that of its producer.So in worst case you may have to write Java(and not the Scala) code to test it